# @loadable/component causes a flash of content in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, code-splitting

I’m trying to optimize [the website](https://ester.co) built with Gatsby framework and according to Google Lighthouse, one of the main issues is unused Javascript code. It looks like the most popular way of dealing with this problem is by excluding components from the main bundle through the [loadable-components](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components#readme) library. The downside of this approach for me is that it causes a flash of content during the initial website load. Is there any way to fix this while keeping loadable-components and if no, are there any other approaches for code-splitting in Gatsby?